# Knockout CSS Binding Not working with Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

say within a table, I have

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
   <tr data-bind="text: somePropertie, css: $parent.setCSS($data)"></tr>
</tbody>
```

and within function **setCSS**, I have a ajax call, and based on the result,

```
if (data == "xxx")
    return "CSSClassName1";
 else
    return "CSSClassName2";
```

And this seems not binding css at all. If I get rid of the ajax call and just return "CSSClassName1", it works.

How do I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Return a promise and use that. Your Ajax call takes some time to complete and the context is likely different from what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: that makes sense. How do I do that? Do you have some sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe setCss() should return something like

```
return {
    CSSClassName1 : data === 'xxx',
    CSSClassName2 : data !== 'xxx'
}
```